# Updating the attribute of managed object locally in coredata and restkit

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

I have been struggling with the RestKit since 15 days now. Once I receive the data from remote, I would also be like to be able to edit the attributes locally and save.

I tried with few different approaches but none seem to be working;

```
 user.attribute = @"new valuel";
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore managedObjectContextForCurrentThread] save:&error];

        if(error)       
             NSLog(@"Error saving %@", error);
```

Second approach was to assign the value to the instance itself and save;

```
user.attribute = @"new valuel";
[user.managedObjectContext save:&error ];
NSlog(@"%@", error)
```

Another try,

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore save:&error];
```

It seems I cannot get the pointer to the context. How is it possible to get the pointer or may be to save the object or is it not possible entirely ? None of these save into the database nor raise any error. What is the problem here ?

Comment: Have you debugged to see the value of the `NSManagedObjectContext` you are trying to use at the time of the call? If the pointer is `nil`, it will fail silently.

Comment: Ok I have checked but the managedObjectContext is not nil ... but it does not update the attribute.

Comment: As soon as I defined some sort of primary Key on my mapping `issueMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"resourceURI" ];` then RestKit would do the merging itself when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem. I also was trying your steps and then opened the database with a pluging of firefox and I could check that db is not updating.

Will let you know if I arrive to any final solution...

**Update:**

I finally got my code working adding the method refreshObject:mergeChanges. Finally my code, is something like this:

```
   // Make changes in managedObjectYouWantToSave 
   [managedObjectYouWantToSave.managedObjectContext refreshObject:managedObjectYouWantToSave mergeChanges:YES];
   [managedObjectYouWantToSave.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Comment: `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` is a method of managedObjectContext and not managedObject..